# recoding value in a column

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm trying to rename values in a column using the mutate and recode function and I'm running into an unused argument error. The column has three possible values: Male, Female, and Unknown.[image]

I tried adding .default=NA to the end of the recode function but that did not work as well. Im trying to get a new column that keeps "unknown"as "unknown", and changes "Male "to Man, and "Female" to Women

Comment: Try: `caregiver_df %>% mutate_at(vars(GENDER), ~case_when(GENDER=="Male" ~ "Man", GENDER=="Female" ~ "Women", TRUE ~ "unknown"))`

Comment: Difficult to help without data. But `iris %>% mutate(Species = recode(Species, "setosa" = "foo"))` works for me (using either quotes or backticks). I wonder whether you have another library loaded with a different `recode()` function ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with how you are using the recode function. Your code is missing quotes around 'Male' and 'Female' inside the recode function. Using `` is not the same.

```
caregiver_df %>% 
     mutate(GENDER = recode(GENDER, 'Male' = "Man", 'Female' = "Women"))
```

Remember that recode will leave the values that are not specified in the function as they are. So if you don't specify 'Unknown', it will remain 'Unknown' in the new column.

Comment: ``iris %>% mutate(Species = recode(Species, `setosa` = "foo"))`` works for me so I'm not sure that backticks is the issue.

Comment: Can you provide output for `str(caregiver_df$GENDER)`?

Comment: the output for str(caregiver_df$GENDER) is "Factor w/ 3 levels "Unknown","Male",..: 3 3 3 2 2 2 3 2 3 3 ...
 - attr(*, "label")= chr "Respondent gender"".  I removed the backticks and used different quotes but am still getting the unused argument error